# Getting weird PHP Xpath result when adding child node - ideas?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

So I have spent about an hour simply trying to add a script element to the head section of an HTML doc. I am following numerous examples that show how to do this, but I am not getting the expected result.

Here is what I have:

```
<head>
    <child1>
    <child2>
</head>
```

I want

```
<head>
    <child1>
    <child2>
    <script></script>
</head>
```

So my code is

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$head = $xpath->query('//head');
$child = $doc->createElement( 'script' );

// append
$head->item(0)->appendChild( $child );
```

This is adding the new script element after the body tag following head... I am ending up with

```
<head>
    <child1>
    <child2>
</head>
<body>
    <script></script>
```

I truly have no idea how this can be, based on everything I understand about xpath and DOM manipulation in PHP.

Ideas?

thanks, Brian

Comment: Can you add a fuller HTML as I have tried to reproduce and it seems to put the script tag where you are expecting.

Comment: I tried it as well and it seems to be working as expected.

Comment: I have a feeling this comes down to some nuances in PHP versions, library versions, etc. See my answer below. Everything is fine now and it really came down to my child node not passing some sort of validation test. Maybe on your systems different versions of PHP or libraries are not resulting in the validation check. Really weird!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think my problem has to do with DOM_HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR.

I think I needed to have properly formatted script tag. I was just trying to verify xpath was getting me the right data and that I could add a child but I didn't realize there was validation that goes on to prevent the adding of child nodes that don't adhere to certain rules!

So this is now working:

```
$head = $xpath->query('//head');
$child = $doc->createElement( 'script' );
$childAttr = $doc->createAttribute( 'src' );
$childAttr->value = $somepath;
$child->appendChild($childAttr);
$head->item(0)->appendChild( $child );
```

Brian

Comment: i think DOMDocument just got pissy about you forgetting the end tags or end `/`'s, i think this XML would work as expected: `<head>
    <child1 />
    <child2 />
</head>
`  (the only difference being that i added 2x  `/`   )